# is there a way in access 2010 to suppress a section header

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

I am trying to suppress a header in a report based on its value.  In the report I am not showing anything in the detail section instead the header of the section contains the field name and its count as a summary report.  However, I want to be able to suppress this header when it has a specific value but if I use a filter then the other headers are also suppressed

Thanks

Comment: when you switch to report design mode you can enter expressions in the header field. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to an IF statement in the format event which does not seem to work on load. If [Qualified Status] <> "Yes" Then PSHeader.Height = 0

Answer (score 0):

You could make it not visible:

```
If [Qualified Status] <> "Yes" Then PSHeader.Visible = False
```

or, if your field is boolean:

```
PSHeader.Visible = [Qualified Status]
```